# The things to consider when choosing a mesh for an electron detector (MCP detector)

Tags: electronics, particle-detectors, instrument

I am designing a electron velocity map imaging setup. I need a copper mesh just infront of the detector to accelerate the electrons towards the MCP detector. I am doing the instrument design for the first time. Can anybody please tell me how to choose a mesh and what are the things should I keep in mind while choosing a mesh for the detector (regarding the number of wires per inch, its transmission etc.)

Comment: Is MCP here "[microchannel plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchannel_plate_detector)"?

Comment: @dmckee: yes, it is Microchannel plate

Comment: It's not a detector I have a lot of experience with especially from a design perspective. There are many commercial off the shelf models available, and I have found [Hamamatsu's application notes (PDF link)](http://sales.hamamatsu.com/assets/applications/ETD/Nir_mcp_pmt.pdf) (which are intended to help you select from among their models) for other detector systems often contain considerable hints on the implications of design choices.

Comment: I have worked with MCPs a lot (they are a common detector used on spacecraft to measure plasma velocity distributions).  I found a useful set of notes in the following PDF [here](http://ham.space.umn.edu/~lbwilson/www/wind_notes_3dp.pdf).  Unfortunately, the accelerator grid mesh material is a topic of which I am not an expert.  The important thing to know is the effective transparency of this grid when estimating the deadtime and efficiency of these detectors.